# Xcode can't check who to blame information

Tags: xcode, git, function

When I used Xcode's `Authors` function, I couldn't load git history and got following prompt. It used work. I don't know how to fix this.[image]

Comment: When I did `cat .git/HEAD`, I got `ref: refs/heads/tool/develop`.
However when I tapped in `echo ref: refs/heads/master`, I got `ref refs/heads/master`.
I am bad at git, do you think that post will help me fix my problem? I think it might be a different problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I got it fixed.

The problem was that I had another `.git` somehow at a subfolder.

After I deleted that git with `rm -rf .git` from that sub folder and restarted Xcode. Everything worked fine.

Comment: Good catch, more precise than my anser. +1

Answer (score 0):

> However when I tapped in echo `ref: refs/heads/master`, I got `ref refs/heads/master`

First, in your case, `HEAD` is supposed to reference the branch `tool/develop`, not `master`.

Second, if you think the `HEAD` should actually represent `master`, then the line to type would be:

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
echo ref: refs/heads/master >.git/HEAD
```

Note the `>.git/HEAD`: it redirects the output of the `echo` to the file `.git/HEAD`.

Do a `git branch -avv` first, to see your local and remote branches.
You can then see if there is any `tool/develop` branch.

Comment: I am using tool/develop branch, I tried to change the head to master as your suggestion, which didn't work for my case unfortunately.