# Xcode - Unable to load authors information

Tags: ios, xcode

When I clicked Editor->Authors in Xcode, some files always complain "Unable to load author information". It happens even in the same subfolder, e.g., A.h is fine but A.m shows this error message.

I did some research but none solved my problem.

1. [XCode: Unable to Load Author Information](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702412)
2. [Xcode can't check who to blame information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053831/xcode-cant-check-who-to-blame-information)

My file path is correct, and there's no other .git folders in my project.

Comment: Does it happen only in one particular repository or in any repository?

Comment: I'm have the same issue, but only in one clone of the same repo. The other clone is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I has similar problem, except "Unable to Load Author Information", Xcode also wasn't showing Source Control changes. For me restart of macOS solved the problem. I had problem only in one repo.